# If $A$ is independent with $B \cap C$, then is $A$ is independent with $B$?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I am wondering whether if $A$ is independent with $B \cap C$, then $A$ is independent with $B$, and if so how to show this. I am inclined to say that this is not true, as then in the definition of mutual independence a lot of our conditions would be superfluous. However, I have been struggling with giving a counterexample or other sort of proof and would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Take $C=\emptyset$.

Comment: Note that $C$ can be manipulated.  The extreme cases you should consider immediately are (1) $C=B$ and (2) $C = \emptyset$.  Have you tried either?  (Depending on the logical scope of $C$, one or the other would work)

Comment: @BrianMoehring isn't the claim true when $C=B$? Also, when $C = \emptyset$, isn't the claim also vacuously true as the definition of independence is unfilled as $\mathbb{P}(B| \emptyset) \neq  \mathbb{P}(B)$ as the LHS is undefined as the empty set has probability zero?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$A = \{2, 3\}$
$B = \{3, 4\}$
$C = \{4, 5\}$

$A \cap (B \cap C) = \emptyset$
$A \cap B = \{3\}$